# tkinter GUI crashes IPython

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I wrote some code with tkinter and it was working just fine. But suddenly, the same code only seems to successfully run about 50% of the time.

If I open Spyder and run the code, it throws no errors, my GUI window doesn't appear, and IPython is hung. Ctrl+C doesn't kill it.

Then I quit the IPython console and let it restart. If i type in some random commands , like 1+1, it won't enter, unless i backspace a few times and retype it. Then, after successfully running some commands, the code runs correctly, my GUI window shows up, but then x-ing out of the GUI window doesn't stop the code. Ctrl+C doesn't kill it.

I'm guessing i have some settings to change, but I can't find anything that seems to make a difference.

I have Python 3.8, Spyder 4.1.4 on Windows 10

```
import tkinter as tk

def increase():
    value = int(lbl_value["text"])
    lbl_value["text"] = f"{value + 1}"
    
def decrease():
    value = int(lbl_value["text"])
    lbl_value["text"] = f"{value - 1}"

window = tk.Tk()

window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure([0, 1, 2], minsize=50, weight=1)

btn_decrease = tk.Button(master=window, text="-", command=decrease)
btn_decrease.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

lbl_value = tk.Label(master=window, text="0")
lbl_value.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn_increase = tk.Button(master=window, text="+", command=increase)
btn_increase.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works for me. Probably something wrong with your PC

Comment: That's the question.... any suggestions on what to check...?